# Can the שנים שעשו recipe be doubled?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, number, melacha-creative-work, reward-punishment

My kid asked: I understand that if two people complete a forbidden activity on *Shabas* by superfluously joining forces to do a task either could do alone, they don't get the punishment one of them would have gotten had he done the task alone. What if four [or, might I add, three] do something two can do? Does the same exemption apply, or do we say that, since it's not something that can be done by one person, there's no exemption for a superfluity of people?

Comment: I don't understand: Are you asking: _If 1 person can carry something, and  4 people go and carry it - are they all exempt?_

Comment: @DannySchoemann, like the question says, "What if four [or, might I add, three] do something two can do?"... not that they do something one can do.

Comment: Couldn't we just say that once one person has begun to take part in a two person job, that it is now a one person job (and if two people joined it would be Shnayim Shehotziuhu)?

Answer (score 2):

> ‏ **משנה:**
>   המוציא כיכר לרשות הרבים, חייב הוציאוהו שניים, פטורים לא יכול אחד להוציאו והוציאוהו שניים, חייבים
>   ורבי שמעון פוטר.‏
>
> **ברטנורא**
>   ואין הלכה כר"ש

If one of the group cannot alone, the both are guilty.

The question seems to understand that if everyone is indispensable for the work, everyone is guilty. But if not, what is the rule. For instance if two men are needed and there are four men at work.

The Gemara asked this question (93ab), when someone or something is not indispensable, he is only helping, what is his status (there are issues in toumeat Massa, in avodot kehuna that need to be made by the right hand). The conclusion is this not necessary help (mesayea) is not relevant.

In conclusion, when two men are making the melacha and both are needed, they're guilty, but if there are four men and two only are needed, each of the four aren't guilty. This is ruled in Rambam Shabbat 1, 16

Tosfot 93a paragraph "amar Rav Zvid", discusses if there is a rabbinical prohibition.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion, and is there any source for it?  The Rambam certainly doesn't say it.

Comment: גמרא צג עמוד ב' לגבי מסיע, בעניין להחזיק את הכלי בימין ושמאל מסיע

Comment: There Fourth leg of a bed. Three are enough, so one leg is only mesayea. @רבות

Comment: +1 Interesting! I would suggest editing sources in to emphasize that Shanyim Sheasauhu is because of Mesayea, and then bring this Gemara as a proof that any Mesayea such as this (even though not stated specifically to Patur you on Shabbos) is enough to make one Patur.